# grep on a shell command in a pipeline scripted script

Tags: jenkins

When I want to make several shell commands my **scripted pipeline** returns the answer of the first command without executing the pipes.
Here is my case:
I want to get specific content on an HTML page. So I do a curl on the page then a grep and finally an awk.

```
def checkState(hostUri, check) {
  node('master') {
    def result = sh 'curl -Lsd "login=username&password=password&button=Login" -c cookie ${hostUri} && grep ${check} && awk -F \'"\' {\'print $2\'}'
    println result
}
```

Only the console return of my pipeline corresponds to the execution of the curl command only without executing the grep and awk.

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Clearcase@8
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
...
</html>
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
```

I have tried different methods such as the use of `'''` or the `new BuildProcess` command which does not exist in scripted pipeline.

Comment: If you want the output of `curl` to go to `grep` and then `awk`, you should use pipes: `curl .. | grep .. | awk`. The `&&` operator is used to chain commands (run a command if the previous one succeeds).

Comment: @Haxiel Indeed, the use of pipes seems to work even inside the scripted pipeline. I don't understand it seems to me that I tried this method first, like in a classic unix terminal...
Thank you very much it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @GotExx That's great. I'll add that as a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Jenkinsfile shown, the variable assignment involves a shell step:

```
def result = sh 'curl -Lsd "login=username&password=password&button=Login" -c cookie ${hostUri} && grep ${check} && awk -F \'"\' {\'print $2\'}'
```

Jenkins would invoke a shell at this point, and pass the following command to it:

```
curl -Lsd "login=username&password=password&button=Login" -c cookie ${hostUri} && grep ${check} && awk -F '"' {'print $2'}
```

The `&&` operator denotes an AND-list. In this case, if the `curl` command succeeds, then the `grep` command is executed and if that succeeds, then the `awk` command would be executed. The standard input/output/error streams of these commands are not connected to each other.

Since the intention here is to parse the output of `curl` using the `grep` and `awk` statements, pipes should be used instead of the `&&` operator:

```
def result = sh 'curl -Lsd "login=username&password=password&button=Login" -c cookie ${hostUri} | grep ${check} | awk -F \'"\' {\'print $2\'}'
```

Consider quoting the `hostUri` & `check` variables as well, in case you end up with special characters in those fields.

One last note: The commands `grep ${check}` & `awk -F '"' {'print $2'}` are technically incomplete without a filename argument or some sort of input. If you run them as-is from a shell terminal, they would simply remain stuck. However, since Jenkins runs the build process non-interactively, I would assume that their standard input streams are redirected from `/dev/null`. In that case, the `grep` commands would fail with a non-zero error code.